# ColdFusion doesn't install Font OpenType TTF

Tags: fonts, coldfusion, pdf-generation, opentype, coldfusion-administrator

How to add `.TTF` OpenType to ColdFusion 2016 (64-Bit)?
The font has a paid Server-License from LinoType.com.
I added it to Font Management, but it doesn't show on PDF-generation.

Comment: Where there any errors when you added the font via the administrator interface? Check the log files.

Comment: @Miguel-F The problem is difference between OpenType and TrueType. I don't see any errors during installation.

Comment: I think ColdFusion supports OpenType OTF fonts. What do you mean _The problem is difference between OpenType and TrueType_?

Comment: What happens when you list all fonts? It could be that CF requires a different font name when embedding. https://gist.github.com/timcunningham/3794186 (NOTE: I gave up on CFDocument and switched to WKHTMLTOPDF w/webfonts. It's a lot more flexible works with most HTML5/CSS3 whereas CFDocument understands only a subset of CSS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the font via Custom Fonts and it doesn't work (some fonts).  When I install it in Windows-Fonts then it works correctly. Here are steps :

1. Copy the font in your `C:\Windows\Fonts`. It will automatically install it.
2. Once it is installed, restart the ColdFusion service.
3. Log into the ColdFusion Admin > Font Management and check your font.